# get just an image from a url, using xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

Hello to the whole community, I wanted to know how to get an image through xpath. I have the following code to download an image using the link of the jpg file

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.elesquiu.com/u/portadas/tapas/7349.jpg'
myfile = requests.get(url)
open('ESQUIU.jpg', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

The problem that arises here, is that the file 7349.jpg is randomly renamed, and for that reason is that I need to go directly through xpath, can someone help me with this? Grateful

webpage info "https://www.elesquiu.com"

Comment: Look at [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library. It allows to parse web page content and getting it parts (e.g. image links) in useful way.

Comment: Add this code as a code, not as a screenshot

Comment: I have modified it. Thanks